# Job ID question

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have been trying to get Job IDs for emails that have been sent on a Journey. When I go to tracking > sends Journey builder sends, there is an external key and not a job id. Where can I find the job id if it is not within tracking > sends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Journey emails are triggered sends, which have JobIDs that are handled differently than batch sends.  They keep their JobIDs until the definition is re-published or you create a new version of your Journey.

You'll need to write a query to get this information.  There's an example on [**this page**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5) that illustrates how Journey sends are relate to _Sent.  Here's an updated version that returns all of the sends to Journey emails in the last 24 hours.

```
select
  j.JourneyName
, j.VersionNumber
, ja.ActivityName as EmailName
, s.EventDate
, su.EmailAddress
, su.SubscriberKey
, s.SubscriberID
, s.JobID
, s.ListID
, s.BatchID
from [_Sent] s
inner join [_JourneyActivity] ja on ja.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
inner join [_Journey] j on j.VersionID = ja.VersionID
inner join [_Subscribers] su on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID
where ja.ActivityType in  ('EMAIL','EMAILV2')
and s.EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24, getdate())
```

Comment: Sweet. Would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at this [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).